# Stored procedure with loops and prepared statements - why does it not work?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to selectively flush a limited set of tables in a particular database - and after bit of investigation (swearing and cussing), I've arrived at:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS local_flush_cache;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE local_flush_cache()
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE a VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE crsr CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=database() AND table_name LIKE 'cache_%';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

OPEN crsr;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH crsr INTO a;

IF done THEN
LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;

SET @s = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', a);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END LOOP;

CLOSE crsr;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The only thing is - it doesn't seem to be working. When I check the contents of the cache tables, they've not been cleared.

When I call the procedure, the only output I get is:

```
mysql> call local_flush_cache();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

And then when I get a row count from one of the cache tables, I get a non-zero result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a lunch break - the problem ended up being the query parameter for the select in the procedure:

```
DECLARE crsr CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=database() AND table_name LIKE 'cache_%';
```

The table I was testing was actually called `cache` - so this would obviously not be matched by the parameter above. The line actually needs to be:

```
DECLARE crsr CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=database() AND table_name LIKE 'cache%';
```

This works great now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting the delimiter to `$$` on the first line, you need to change the semicolon on the **second** line to `$$` instead.

Comment: good point - I've fixed the misplaced DROP, but this is not the actual cause of the problem...

Comment: @horuskol I tested the procedure on my machine, and it works correctly.

Comment: @horuskol Try running the `SELECT` used in the cursor, are all of your cache tables in the resultset?

Comment: @Scrum in hindsight, that would have saved a short bit of hairpulling on my part ;)